# ios - ASIHTTPRequest and HUD Loading View Start and Stop

Tags: ios, progress-bar, asihttprequest, hud

I have successfully implemented the ASIHTTPRequest framework to download a file from a URL and it saves in my Document Directory - YIPPIE!!!

Now I would like to show a Progress of some sort, so that the user can what is going on.

With the UIWebViewDelegate there are the following methods - I was hoping to use something similar.

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Is there something similar to use with ASIHTTP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example mixing [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and ASI.

The idea is you start your updating before the begin the request and you end the updating in either the completion or failed blocks.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = @"Updating…";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
   NSError *error = [request error];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thank you :-) it was 1am when I posted the question hence the late reply:-)